# pointer-to-member-function type requires an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, boost-variant

What is the matter of the error, which produces the following code?

```
struct foo
{
    void call(void (foo::*ptr)()) &&
    {
        (*this.*ptr)();
    }
};
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Don't you think that wrapping the perfectly fine keywords `sizeof` and `alignof` inside templates is a little overkill?

Comment: Also, this is a hell of a lot of code. Think you could [simplify it a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @zneak I needed metafunctions, rather than naked keywords.

Comment: @zneak It is minimal practicable example, which contains the interesting error. Each function and metafunction contains at maximum two lines of code (except of typedefs and static_asserts).

Comment: I believe that [this](http://ideone.com/YNtSTt) is the minimal practicable example, and that the solution is to use `(std::move(*this).*ptr)`.

Comment: Good work. Can you make an answer?

Comment: By *practicable* I mean *real-life practicable*.

Comment: -1, wall of code.  For this question to be useful to later users, you need to less 'here is a pile of code please debug' and more 'here is code that produces an error I do not understand' -- http://sscce.org describes what is useful, where you want simple code that generates the error, not a small irrelevant to the error metaprogramming library.

Comment: Ok, I'll satisfy the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the member pointer has the rvalue qualifier, the compiler must be told that `*this` is to be treated as an rvalue by using `std::move` on it:

```
(std::move(*this).*ptr)();
```

Comment: Please, rewrite your answer, because the question was altered.